# Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalReferenceCollectionBuilderExtensions'

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have just moved from asp.net core 2.2 to 3.1 and now I am getting following exception

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalReferenceCollectionBuilderExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational,
>   Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Comment: Any news on this? I noticed HasConstraintName is not available in 3.1 but I haven't found a suitable replacement for it yet

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalreferencecollectionbuilderextensions?view=efcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-3.1, that class (`RelationalReferenceCollectionBuilderExtensions`) no longer exists in 3.1.